# How to create drop down list in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

This is my controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

This is my Create view part

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Select Your User Type", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.DropDownList("Name")*@
            @Html.DropDownList("Name",(SelectList)ViewBag.Name )
        </div>
    </div>
```

i can load the form with drop down. but when I am try to save the record it gives an error "The ViewData item that has the key 'Name' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'."

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Dropdown List From SelectList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242981/asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-from-selectlist)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var role in context.Roles)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem {Text = role.Name, Value = role.Value});
        }

        var result = new SelectList(items);
        ViewBag.Name = result;
        return View();
}
```

**View**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Name",ViewBag.Name)
```

But can I suggest that you avoid `ViewBag` and use strongly typed models.

Look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: What exception are you now getting??

Comment: Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'Name' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I have updated. I am not sure what `context` is but you need to pass a string and an int (value) for the SelectListItem