# Generic ToSelectListItem method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, generics

I have about 10 very simple tables in database:

```
create table EmploymentStatus
(
    Id int identity(1,1) Primary Key,
    Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

These tables are used for `DropDownLists` on registration view, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EmploymentStatus, Model.EmploymentStatusList, Resource.EmploymentStatus, new { @class = "form form-control" })
```

`DropDownListFor` requires a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList` as a collection. 
So, I created a method:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList(IQueryable<EmploymentStatu> statuses)
{
    return statuses.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = m.Name,
        Value = m.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();
}
```

The problem is that I have to create a method for each of ten entities. Is there a good way of writing some generic method, like this:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList(IQueryable<T> collection)
{
    return collection.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = m.Name,
        Value = m.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options:

**If you can implement an interface on the entity**

```
public interface ISelectable
{
    string Name { get; }
    int Id { get; }
}
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    where T: ISelectable
{
    return collection.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = m.Name,
        Value = m.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();
}
```

**Using delegates**

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, string> nameGetter, Func<T, int> idGetter)
{
    return collection.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = nameGetter(m),
        Value = idGetter(m).ToString()
    }).ToList();
}
```

Usage :

```
m.EmploymentStatus.ToSelectItemList(e => e.Name, e => e.Id);
```

The second option is more verbose to use, but you get a ton more flexibility, since you don't have to clutter your data model with useless interface implementation, and you are free to use any property names for `Name` or `Id`

Answer (score 8):

You can define an interface for all entities that you are going to use for DropDownLists like

```
public interface IDropDownItem
{
   int Id {get; set;}
   string Name {get; set;}
}
```

then

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) 
   where T : IDropDownItem
{
    return collection.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = m.Name,
        Value = m.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();
}
```

It would be better to make `ToSelectItemList` as extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectItemList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
        where T : Program
    {
        return collection.Select(m => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = m.Name,
            Value = m.Id.ToString()
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, should i inherit this interface in entity class? Because every time I will update my model from db this will be missed

Comment: the approach using delegate is more better in my opinion as suggested by @Titian

Comment: @kir.gera yes you should implement the interface. His solution has a flaw though, you should change `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` otherwise you will get an error. You can't do LINQ to EF on interfaces, you can do it on an `IEnumerable` as that will get handled in memory and  no SQL has to be genearetd

Comment: Also I would have made the method an extension method (and I did in my answer)

Comment: @kir.gera Yes, you should. It is additional work but you will get a nice code where you're going to call it `m => m.EmploymentStatus.ToSelectItemList()`. And it makes that method more testable. As I write before (and Titian) it would be better to make it as an extension method. See updates

Answer (score 3):

> `DropDownListFor` requires a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` selectList as a collection

There's already a class for that, namely [`SelectList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
var selectListItems = new SelectList(items, "Id", "Name");
```

No need for new extension methods whatsoever. I thought `SelectList()` also has an overload with expressions for the key/value members instead of strings, but I may have found that somewhere else.

See also [ASP.NET MVC Dropdown List From SelectList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242981/asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-from-selectlist).

Comment: I didn't know about the class, generally it is better to use built-in classes, however, I don't think properties as magic uncheckable strings is a great idea, would still prefer a more type safe option.