# SelectListItem not setting via dropdown after extending SelectList class

Tags: c#, selectlist, selectlistitem

I am trying to extend the SelectListItem class to add another property called CardColor. However when I try to access the property in my controller I get

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object....
>               return View("StringView", c.IssueSelected.CardColor);

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CardCreate(UpdateCardFormOptions c)
{
    return View("StringView", c.IssueSelected.CardColor);
}
```

View

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
<p><label>Issue Category*:</label>  @Html.DropDownListFor(c => @Model.IssueSelected, Model.IssueList, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 350px" })</p>
}
```

Model:

```
public IssueSelectListItem IssueSelected { get; set; }


 public List<IssueSelectListItem> IssueList = new List<IssueSelectListItem>() {
            new IssueSelectListItem() {Text="xxx", Value="yyy",CardColor="pink"},
};

public class IssueSelectListItem : SelectListItem
{
    public string CardColor { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20243119/1634753) gave me a clue, turns out I needed to set the value CardColor in the View, I couldnt just set the object equivalent. My View needed to set CardColor based on my dropdown choice like this:

```
<p><label>Issue Category*:</label>  @Html.DropDownListFor(c => @Model.IssueSelected.CardColor, Model.IssueList, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 350px" })</p>
```

**Not going to accept my own answer, still hoping someone has a better one, this just solved my immediate problem**

Comment: Your `IssueSelectListItem` is a bit pointless since the `DropDownListFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as the 2nd parameter, and your additional `CardColor` property is just ignored. And your `IssueSelected` property makes no sense either ans will never bind correctly (you cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object - it posts back only a simple value). Its not clear what it is you are trying to do with your code

Comment: @StephenMuecke my goal is to pass multiple parameters to a SelectList and be able to save them all, eg based on which SelectListItem they choose I would also like to retain info about the CardColor that was associated with it

Comment: Unless you were to create your own extension method to create a `<select>`, then you cannot pass anything other that the `Text` and `Value` properties (if you inspect the html you are generating, you will see that there is no `CardColor="pink"` attribute. And in any case, a `<select>` only posts back a simple value - the value of your selected option (which in your case will be `"xxx"`)