# Linq expression set multiple attributes in form

Tags: c#, linq, drop-down-menu

Because of some [c# wierdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159564/selectlistitem-not-setting-via-dropdown-after-extending-selectlist-class) due to the fact that I extended a class I cannot simply set the value of a dropdown like normal:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => @Model.IssueSelected, Model.IssueList)
```

I need to set each property. How can I write the linq expression to set multiple things eg Text and Value and CardColor (part of extended class). I guessed at this syntax but it is obviously wrong:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => {@Model.IssueSelected.CardColor,@Model.IssueSelected.Text}, Model.IssueList)
```

Comment: What are you trying to display? CardColor?

Comment: I am trying to pass the Object Model.IssueSelected back to the controller, but for some reason it isnt setting properly (returns null)