# Index was out of range. In razor page

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I have a asp.net core project. In my model I have one entity that its name is Brand. You can see that below.

```
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CategoryBrand> CategoryBrands { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the section of my view that I have problem with that.

```
<select asp-for="@Model.CategoryBrands[0].CatId">
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Categories)
{
   <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
}
</select>
```

When I want to edit one of my entities that does not have any categorybrands I get this error

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection
```

I understand the error reason, because there is nothing in brand.categorybrands collection, **but consider that I need this select, because in EditBrand somebody maybe want to add a category in edit page.**

Comment: Shouldn't the tag helper look like: '<select asp-for="Brand" asp-items="@Model.CategoryBrands"/>?

Comment: @Menahem before the foreach error happens, and in CreateBrand it works and does not have problem.

Comment: Looks like `Model.CategoryBrands` is an empty collection and you are trying to access the first item from that. Refer [Select Tag helper in Asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc/34624217#34624217) for samples on how to use select tag helper.

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem and It works well. Could you post more reproducible code or share sample on git?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that there is a problem with `your ViewBag.Categories`. Check your ViewBag for its values when there are no categories. A silly fix to it would be to add validation but my suggestion is to use`SelectList` instead. 
`SelectList` will give you lesser flexibility but more robustness in razor view.

Here is a how it is used:
[ASP.NET MVC Dropdown List From SelectList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242981/asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-from-selectlist)